# What is this SVG XLink meant to do

Tags: html, css, svg, navigation, xlink

I am working with an image that has XLinks such as follows: -

```
<defs>
  <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M0 0h250v182.6H0z"/>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
  <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible"/>
</clipPath>
<g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_)">
```

There are 1/2 doz of these that all seem to (my first guess) suggest go to previous section?

I can understand external links but can someone please shed some light on what the author may have been intending here? the common denominator seems to be: - d="M0 0h250v182.6H0z"

Can I just get rid of them?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answer @qrsngky

The author repeats this 3 different times in the one document so clipPath must be difficult or d="M0 0h250v182.6H0z" may be the copyright who knows.

Anyway I replace the Xlink:hrefs with hrefs so I can drop the namespace reference.

Cheers

Comment: As [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) it is an old version of the [href attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href). The use element needs an href to work with ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use)) but for newer browsers one can just use "href" instead of "xlink:href".

Comment: These are rectangular [clip-paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) (250 wide,182.6 high). Quite often, graphic applications add unnecessary clip-paths when converting graphics to svg. If your svg has a viewBox like "0 0 250 182.6" you can safely delete all clip-paths and clipping rules